# beacons push notification in LAN without internet

Tags: server, apple-push-notifications, push, local

i'm learning about beacons,i have some days looking for information and i would like to know if this scenario can be possible.

i'm talking about an **local server** (local pc, maybe) sending data/information through beacons to android or ios devices. its possible use this kind of services (marketing messages, publicity, and others) **without** internet? **With** an local area network, maybe?

Comment: the beacons you mentioned is the device like "iBeacon" ? too broad anyways.

Comment: What do you mean with "too broad"?
Yes, i'm testing with generics beacons an iBeacons.

Comment: **too broad**: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Basically we worked only with bluethooth the beacon , basic communication tasks. But we never got to use the service "Nearby API " or " API Proximity " for example, because our idea was to use this kind of PUSH notifications from a local server and not have to upload anything to the cloud.

The next step for us is to send these PUSH notifications through the beacon. Many thanks.

Comment: Local notification does not require Internet connection.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63443012/887092 - broadly you cannot send a proper iOS/Android push notification without internet

Answer (score 0):

iBeacon / generic beacons do not require Internet to work. With suitable beacon layout (Android), or beacon UUID, the device can detect the beacon proximity (require Bluetooth & Wi-Fi to turn on). With the proximity event of beacon, you can trigger other methods like communicating with local servers, as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Oh, I understood the idea, working with events. Thank you so much!!